# Is the Accessibility permission of Maxlock safe?

Tags: applications, permissions, accessibility

Is it safe to use the [Maxlock](https://github.com/Maxr1998/MaxLock) app if it asks for accessibility permission to work properly? I need it to lock the Settings app. I am aware that this kind of permission could be dangerous, but Maxlock is an open-source app. I don't know...

Comment: Please edit your post and add the link to the app in PlayStore you are talking about.

Comment: It's not on PlayStore,i've found it on github.Here's the link https://github.com/Maxr1998/MaxLock

Comment: As an Xposed module the code will be executed in every app process on the phone, so I am not sure why the author requests accessibility services permission.

Comment: @Robert I guess it's a fallback mechanism for unrooted devices. The relevant code is on [`AppLockService.kt`](https://github.com/Maxr1998/MaxLock/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/Maxr1998/xposed/maxlock/no_xposed/AppLockService.kt).

Comment: @Robert So,it could be dangerous to use the app with accessibility?

Comment: In general I would not recommend to use a security app which is unmaintained for more than 3 years and that had been removed from Google Play Store (unknown if Google or the author removed it).

Comment: Ok. I understand